# How to filter out all letters but not all special characters in a string

Tags: java, string, filter

I am writing a program for my Java class that is supposed to raise 2 to whatever power the user puts in and is to terminate when the user enters -1. The raising to the power and everything like that works, but the code I have to filter out letters also filters out special characters. Any suggestions?

Here is the code the filters out the characters:

```
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Comment: "Any suggestions?" Read a primer, post a simple program that can be compiled and run, and show the exact place it is going wrong.

Comment: To reinforce my point, my teacher would say "print a listing" and that act would usually re-engage my brain, and often realise the problem before even reading the hard copy.

Comment: I would recommend not ignoring non-digits, instead the program should just display an error message indicating that the input is not a number when incorrect input is given.  You can then just use a try/catch block around Integer.valueOf(inputString) that catches a NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code and let me know,

`inputString = inputString.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]","");`

The regex used is: `[^-?0-9]` which means:

replace any character other than `-`(minus) or `digits`. You  don't have to worry about `+` sign